# "Extended" in the new Freebase API

Tags: api, freebase

Is it possible to use "extended" in the new freebase API?

I have a few MQL read queries that retrieve images, "notable for" and article text for a topic in one call via the legacy API, but is this possible in the new API?

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Freebase team have decided not to support Extended MQL in the new API, so this isn't possible. I don't think anyone's particularly happy about this decision, but it's been made so we're stuck with it :-(

Comment: Ah ok, that is a shame they've removed it. Thanks very much for your help. Ben

Comment: We have removed Extended MQL, but we are working on another way to do this, unfortunately not ready yet.